# admin edit form content showing in left

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml

I'd created a module for admin where I need to display a form. But its not appearing properly and the form is not submitting.
**screenshot**
[image: screenshot]

**directory structure**
[image: directory structure]

The code is as below

*Excellence/PosImg/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController*

```
class Excellence_PosImg_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('catalog/posimg')
        ;
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('posimg/adminhtml_posImg_edit'))
                ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('posimg/adminhtml_posImg_edit_tabs'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

*Excellence/PosImg/Block/Adminhtml/PosImg/Edit*

```
class Excellence_PosImg_Block_Adminhtml_PosImg_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'posImg';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_index';

        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('posimg')->__('Export Data'));

        $this->_formScripts[] = "
            function toggleEditor() {
                if (tinyMCE.getInstanceById('posimg_content') == null) {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'posimg_content');
                } else {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'posimg_content');
                }
            }

            function saveAndContinueEdit(){
                editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
            }
        ";
    }

    public function getHeaderText() {
        return Mage::helper('posimg')->__('Export POS Images');
    }

}
```

*Excellence/PosImg/Block/Adminhtml/PosImg/Edit/Tabs*

```
class Excellence_PosImg_Block_Adminhtml_PosImg_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('posImg_tabs');
        $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
        $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('posimg')->__('Item Information'));
    }

    protected function _beforeToHtml() {
        $this->addTab('form_section', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('posimg')->__('Item Information'),
            'title' => Mage::helper('posimg')->__('Item Information'),
            'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('posimg/adminhtml_posImg_edit_tab_form')->toHtml(),
        ));

        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

}
```

*Excellence/PosImg/Block/Adminhtml/PosImg/Edit/Form*

```
class Excellence_PosImg_Block_Adminhtml_PosImg_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

    protected function _prepareForm() {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
            'id' => 'edit_form',
            'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
            'method' => 'post',
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
                )
        );

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

}
```

*Excellence/PosImg/Block/Adminhtml/PosImg/Edit/Tab/Form*

```
class Excellence_PosImg_Block_Adminhtml_PosImg_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

    protected function _prepareForm() {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('posImg_form', array('legend' => Mage::helper('posimg')->__('Export POS Images')));

        $fieldset->addField('skip', 'checkbox', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('posimg')->__('Skip images already exists?'),
            'name' => 'skip',
            'onclick' => 'this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;'
        ));
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

}
```

Comment: http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-admin-gridview-85 i'd suggest u to refer this tutorial to create a form/grid in admin panel.. it worked fine for me!

Comment: @Swetha: thanks for the link. it may help the future visitors. But it doesn't help me in solving my problem. If following the guide in the link I need to change my module name.

Comment: Did u get any solution? I have same problem.

Comment: yeah... I do not have the complete answer to this problem but the issue was with the `$this->_blockGroup = 'posImg';` in `Excellence/PosImg/Block/Adminhtml/PosImg/Edit`. As in [app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php](http://freegento.com/doc/d8/d44/_adminhtml_2_block_2_widget_2_form_2_container_8php-source.html)'s `_prepareLayout()` it uses this value to create the `form`.

Comment: In my case, I forget to create Form.php file..

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is **$this->_blockgroup** and **$this->_controller** are incorrect, here's an explanation. If we look at line 82 of

app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php

You can see it uses the _blockGroup and _controller to load the correct file path.

```
$this->setChild('form', $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_blockGroup . '/' . $this->_controller . '_' . $this->_mode . '_form'));
```

You have

```
    $this->_blockGroup = 'posImg';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_index';
```

Which translates to posImg/adminhtml_index_edit_tab_form you will have got an exception in your log along the lines of exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_posImg.. I'm assuming here because posImg does not exist Magento defaults back to Mage_.

This should be

```
    $this->_blockGroup = 'excellence_posImg';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_posImg';
```

Translating to Excellence_posImg/adminhtml_posImg_edit_tab_form

This is the correct path app/code/local/Excellence/posImg/Block/Adminhtml/posImg/Edit/Tab/Form.php

I resolved the same issue myself by adding print_r($type) on the first line of the try in the createBlock function in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php

You will see the block names that are being called.

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing is when adding your content to the tab your should link the form and not the tab form.

```
'content' => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('posimg/adminhtml_posImg_edit_form')->toHtml(),
```

But I do not think that is the only problem with your code. I would suggest having a look at a few tutorials or simply take an example from magento core and work through it.